# Using a DateFormatter with a JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, date-formatting, jformattedtextfield

I am using a `JFormattedTextField` in combination with a `DateFormatter`. I've seen examples of this kind of text field using `MaskFormatter` in which a user can type in values and overwrite existing ones (e.g. the placeholder characters) without having to erase them manually. Is it possible to do the same thing with a `DateFormatter`? For example, I want to use `00:00:00` as the placeholder string, and the time should be in the format `HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 1):

[JSpinner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) is better and nicer [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) for [Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) instance, than  [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#defaultformatterapi), I think that more confortable and intuitive